# Setting <li> class during building the list

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file of products, where I am looping through the products, and adding them to a list which is then printed. They are printing and it's all working fine, until I come to wanting to filter the products. To filter the products, I need to use the class identifiers in the `<li>` tag.

To begin with, I've set it to empty, but I need to set the values, as they are coming from the JSON file, so I am presuming there is a way to do this. Below, I've attempted to set it, I've also printed categories out (commented out now), to check that they are the values I want, which they are. So now, I want to set the class in `<li class=''>` to the variable categories.

```
var output = "<ul id='productList'>";
$.getJSON("products.json", function(result) 
{

    var output = "<ul id='productList'>";

    for (var i in result.products) 
    {
        output += "<li class=''>" + "<figure class='prodInfo'>" + "<a href='#link'>" +" <span class='link'>" + "</span>" + "</a>" + "<img src='Images/saxophone.png' alt='instrument' width='120' height='120'> " + "<figcaption>" + result.products[i].make + " " 
        + result.products[i].model + "<br/>" + result.products[i].name + "<br/>" + result.products[i].price + "</figcaption>" + "</figure>" + "</li>";

        var categories = result.products[i].category;
        //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = categories;
        //$("li").addClass(categories);


    }

    output += "</ul>";
```

I'm quite lost, and I think I have misunderstood the way I am trying to do it, so any help on where to go or how to set it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So why not `<li class='" + categories + "'>` just define the variable above that line etc.

Comment: Oh golly, that's the easiest thing, I completely overlooked that. I thought along those lines, and couldn't process it! Thank you so much!